# Galois group of finite field extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, automorphism-group

Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be a prime. Let $F=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, $n\geq1$, be a finite field of $p^n$ elements containing $M=\mathbb{Z}/(p)$. I would like to show that $\mathrm{Gal}(F/M)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(n)$.

Here's my work so far. It is easy to show that $F/M$ is a simple field extension (i.e. there exists an element $\alpha\in F$ such that $F=M(\alpha)$) because of the existence of a generator of the multiplicative group of the field. Then the Galois group of $F/M$ contains the automorphisms of $F$ sending such generator to roots contained in $F$ of the minimal polynomial of the generator over $M$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at what happens with the Frobenius automorphism

Comment: I suppose you could write $\;\Bbb Z/(p)=:\Bbb F_p=\;$ the prime field with $\;p\;$ elements...This is a rather standard notation, though perhaps not a universal one. You wouldn't also need to point out  $\;F\;$ contains this field: it must to and we should know it. Finally, read the other comment: it may be important.

Comment: Since $x^p -x$ has at most $p$ roots in $F$, $M$ is the fixed field of the Frobenius thus $Gal(F/M) $ is the cyclic group generated by the Frobenius.